# Opening non-utf-8 csv file Python 3

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I have a csv file that is not `utf-8` encoded. And it seems impossible to open it in Python 3. I've tried all kinds of `.encode()` `Windows-1252`, `ISO-8859-1`, `latin-1` – every time I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 279: invalid start byte
```

The `0xfc` byte is the German `ü`

I concede that my judgment is impaired since I was fighting with this issue for a long time now. What am I missing? I've always had problems with unicode in Python, but this one just seems especially stubborn.

This is the first time I try to work with Python 3 and as far as I understand there is no `.decode()` anymore, which could have solved the issue in the second.

EDIT:
code to open file:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
csv.reader(open('myFile.csv', 'r'), delimiter = ';')
```

Comment: How is your file encoded and how does your code to open the file look like?

Comment: @Matthias that's the problem – I didn't create the file, and have no Idea how it is encoded.
Edited my code in the question.

Comment: In the `open`, specify `encoding="latin-1"` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply specify encoding when **opening** the file:

```
with open("xxx.csv", encoding="latin-1") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    ...
```

or with your own code:

```
csv.reader(open('myFile.csv', 'r', encoding='latin1'), delimiter = ';')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was getting desperate.